# Drop down box filled with mysql rows php

Tags: php, html, mysql, row

I am currently working on a school project. My goal is to develop a dynamic web page that allows people to retrieve data from a database. I want to create a few drop down boxes that allows users to narrow down the data from my database I have created.

For example, I have "year" as one column in my database because I have gathered data from multiple years. I would like to establish a way for users to select a specific year by using an HTML drop down box. How exactly do I go about coding something like this using PHP and my database?

Here is my code so far, but I can't seem to get anywhere with this.

```
<select name='year'>
<?php
$query = "select distinct year from test order by year";

$result = $result->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<option value='".$row->year."'>".$row->year."</option>";
}

?>
</select>
```

With this code, I am getting a drop down box, but no choices are given. It is blank. Any ideas? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try using {$row->year} instead of ".$row->year."

Comment: Code is wrong.  $result = $result->query($query);  From where you got $result

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Drilling down Data and Looping with Loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562796/php-drilling-down-data-and-looping-with-loops)

Answer (score 1):

fetch_assoc() return the associative array not an object,should be accessed like array

```
$query = "select distinct year from test order by year";
$result = $result->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<option value='".$row['year']."'>".$row['year']."</option>";
}
```

Comment: When the `value` and the text are the same, you don't need to declare the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name='year'>
<?php
$query = "select distinct year from test order by year";

$result = $result->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
echo "<option value='".$row->year."'>".$row->year."</option>";
}

?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the result as objects you should use fetch_object.
So your loop should change as below:

`while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {`

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
 $sql=mysql_query("select distinct year from test order by year");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
     echo "<option value='".$row["year"]."'>".$row["year"]."</option>";
 }
```